# Inter-cyclical force or motion

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, gravity, quantum-spin, interactions

Is there an Inter-cyclical force/motion, between micro particles, and orbiting bodies, or between Sub-Atomic particles, Atoms, Molecules, and the next magnitude in the size of matter?
Are particles spinning in the opposite direction to atoms, and atoms rotating in the opposite direction to molecules, if so could this persist on up to larger objects such as a planet?
Creating some kind of harmony between the different states.

Answer (score 0):

> Are particles spinning in the opposite direction to atoms, and atoms rotating in the opposite direction to molecules,

At the microcosm level of atoms and molecules up to micrometer dimensions the framework is quantum mechanical. Quantum mechanics is a probabilistic theory and does not obey the intuitions of every day.

[Angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) is conserved absolutely, both at the quantum frame and at the classical frame and its conservation is utilized in finding solutions of the equations  at both frames. That is all.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your input, it is most appreciated!